# Removing Hyperlink Mouse-Over Color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tumblr

Tumblr's "Stationery" theme highlights the Home hyperlink in a grey color that I've yet to find out how to remove. It looks terrible and anything I've tried in the CSS (Such as `a:hover {color: black; text-decoration: none; font-weight: none }` ) doesn't seem to work.

Any recommendations? My full style block is below:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        background: url(http://s15.postimg.org/5elcqo9q1/paper.png) repeat-y;  
        background-position: top center;
        background-color: {color:Background}; 
    }
    .tag, .search_query {
         font-weight: bold;
    }
    {CustomCSS}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find out the class which is applying this `a` hover color.

Comment: Or try giving `a:hover {color: black!important;}`.

Comment: There must be some other styling that is overriding your styles. Use Developer Console of your browser to investigate further.

Comment: They have more specific styles than what you are trying with just `a {}` , they have `#stat-articles article header .stat-notes a, #stat-articles article header time a {}`

Comment: @Anup Very bad way of tackling the issue

Comment: @Alien...Bad but fast way.. ;)

Comment: @Anup fast spoil things

Comment: @Alien I am trying to break this habit as fast as possible.... lol

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you an exact answer without seeing more of the code, but to give you a bit of direction I can make a few suggestions:

It sounds like an issue of specificity, or precedence of order. This means that the styles from the theme are probably overriding your styles because they either are located somewhere that gives them a higher precedence (embedded/inline, in a different stylesheet, lower down in the file, etc..) OR the style declaration is more specific which causes it to take priority.

I'd say the best bet would be to really track down the hierarchy of the elements, figure out the style declaration that is causing the grey color, and then make sure to write a very specific declaration to target that element.

If all else fails, you can use `color: black !important;` to force a higher precedence, though this is usually best avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do this thing, it will work.

```
a:hover {color: black!important;}
```

OR find the wrapper class for your a tag & apply this way :-

```
.YourClass a:hover {color: #000000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-decoration-style: none` and then `color: black`